# Tree algorithm and sum value of node

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on the programming exercise at HackerRank.
I made data structure code like this. But I couldn't figure out a plan how can I implement program to sum up the value of tree node.
Would you give me some advice for my code?
If I have some fault in the data structure which i've made, please tell me abount that.

Thank you.

[HackerRank exercise]

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-tree

[Code]

I wrote this program and I couldn't how can I get futher to sum up the value of tree.

```
class Tree:
    """
    Original Tree Structure which is representing the Input
    """
    def __init__(self, value, position):
        self.value = value
        self.position = position
        self.connection = []

    def set_connection(self, connection):
        self.connection.append(connection)

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.connection = value

    def get_value(self, position):
        return self.value

    def get_sum(self):
        return self.value

    def get_position(self):
        return self

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # ----- Initializing ------
    N = int(input())
    values = input().split()
    T = []
    a = 0
    for value in values:
        T.append(Tree(int(value), a))
        a += 1

    input_list = []
    for i in range(N-1):
        in_con = input().split()
        T[int(in_con[0])-1].set_connection(int(in_con[1])-1)
        T[int(in_con[1])-1].set_connection(int(in_con[0])-1)
        input_list.append(in_con)

    # ----- Start solve problem -----
    ~~~~~~~~~~snip~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Please post entire text of the task here, on SO

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Do you want to sum the values of all `Tree` instances in `T`? In this case the solution would be `sum(t.value for t in T)`

Comment: Sorry about my mess. I'll paste entire excercise text with another comment.  And my question is how can I get the value of the sum value of separated Tree.

Comment: Problem Statement

Atul is into graph theory, and he is learning about trees nowadays. He observed that the removal of an edge from a given tree T will result in the formation of two separate trees, T1 and T2.

Each vertex of the tree T is assigned a positive integer. Your task is to remove an edge, such that the Tree_diff of the resultant trees is minimized. Tree_diff is defined as the following:F(T) = Sum of numbers written on each vertex of a tree T
 Tree_diff(T) = abs(F(T1) - F(T2))

Comment: nput Format
The first line will contain an integer N, i.e. the number of vertices in the tree.
The next line will contain N integers separated by a single space, i.e. the values assigned to each of the vertices.
The next N−1 lines contain a pair of integers eah, separated by a single space, that denote the edges of the tree.
In the above input, the vertices are numbered from 1 to N.

Output Format
A single line containing the minimum value of Tree_diff.

Constraints
3≤N≤105
1≤ number written on each vertex ≤1001

Comment: More detailed information is https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to write the full code, but you can follow this pseudoCode :

```
   1) Create tree with node structure as:
              Node{
                     int value;
                     int sum; //sum of all nodes under this node(treating this as root)
                     List<Node> childs;
                   }
   2) totalSum = root.getSum()// this represents the sum of all values in your tree.

   3)min =Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
   for each Node in tree{
     // below quantity represents the sum of other half which is created by removing the incoming edge of current node. 
     half = totalsum - Node.getSum();   
     if(Math.abs(Node.getSum() - half) < min){
         min = Math.abs(Node.getSum() - half);
     }
   }
   min will be the value;
```